# Implementing Pseudocode For ID3 Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree, id3

I'm trying to implement the pseudo code for the id3 algorithm that is given below

```
function ID3 (I, 0, T) {   
/* I is the set of input attributes 
 * O is  the output attribute 
 * T is a set of training data 
 * 
 * function ID3 returns a decision tree */

 if (T is empty) { return a single node with the value "Failure"; } 

 if (all records in T have the same value for O) {return a single node with that value;} 

 if (I is empty) { 
     return a single node with the value of the most frequent value of O in T; 
    /* Note: some elements in this node will be incorrectly classified */ 
 }

/* now handle the case where we can’t return a single node */ 

compute the  information gain for each attribute in I relative to T;

let X be the attribute with largest Gain(X, T) of the attributes in I; 

let {x_j| j=1,2, .., m} be the values of X; 

let {T_j| j=1,2, .., m} be the subsets of T when T is 
    partitioned according the value of X; 

    return a tree with the root node labelled X and 
    arcs labelled x_1, x_2, .., x_m, where the arcs go to the 
    trees ID3(I-{X}, O, T_1), ID3(I-{X}, O, T_2), .., ID3(I-{X}, O, T_m);
}
```

Here is what I have so far

```
def ID3(attributes, class_set, training_data):
    if not training_data:
        tree = Tree("Empty")
    elif np.sum(class_set) == len(class_set):
        #there are only two possible values for a class_set
        #0 or 1 so if the class set is all 1 return 1 else return 0
        tree = Tree("1")
    elif np.sum(class_set) == 0:
        tree = Tree("0")
    elif not attributes:
        if np.count_nonzero(class_set) > (len(class_set) - np.count_nonzero(class_set)):
            #if there are more ones than zeroes in the class set return 1
            #else return 0
            tree = Tree("1")
        else:
            tree = Tree("0")
    else:
        max_value = 0
        node_name = ""
        for value in range (len(training_data[0]) -1):
            ig = IG(training_data, value) #calculating the gain for each attribute and keeping track of it
                                          #largest ig is node_name
            if ig > max_value:
                max_value = ig
                node_name = attributes[value][0]
                col_n = value
        tree = Tree(node_name)
    true_values = []
    false_values = []


    #the code here is splitting the partition according to the values of x which are
    #always 0 and 1
    for binary_values in range(len(training_data) -1):
        if training_data [binary_values + 1][col_n] == '1':
            true_values.append(training_data[binary_values + 1])
        else:
            false_values.append(training_data[binary_values + 1])
    true_values = np.array(true_values)
    false_values = np.array(false_values)
    #since the data_table actually contains the names of the column I'm  deleting them here
    true_values = np.delete(true_values, col_n, 1)
    false_values = np.delete(false_values, col_n, 1)
    #T is now partiontioned according to the values of X
```

I'm having trouble implementing the last few lines of the psuedocode which are

```
    return a tree with the root node labelled X and 
    arcs labelled x_1, x_2, .., x_m, where the arcs go to the 
    trees ID3(I-{X}, O, T_1), ID3(I-{X}, O, T_2), .., ID3(I-{X}, O, T_m);
```

I don't get what the pseudo code means when its referring to arcs. I'm assuming it's referring to the branches but I don't know how to return an arc or how to make the actual recursive call on it.